# DotNetZip streaming

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I'm trying to zip a bunch of files and make the data consumable via a stream.

I would like to keep the memory footprint as small as possible.

My idea was to implement a Stream where I've got a bunch of FileStream objects as data members. When the Read method on my Stream was called, I would read some data from one of my file streams and use the ZipOutputStream instance to write zipped data to temporary storage stream which i would then forward the read request to.

This temporary storage stream would just be a queue of bytes. As these bytes are moved into a buffer (via a call to Read), they'd be deleted from the queue. This way, I'd only be storing the bytes that haven't been read yet.

Unfortunately, it seems as though when i dispose a ZipOutputStream it needs to write in random file locations in order to create a valid zip file. This will prevent me from using my "fleeting data" solution.

Hopefully this is all clear :)

Is there another way to minimize memory footprint when creating zip files? Please Help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ZipOutputStream` doesn't need to write to random locations in the output stream (in other words, call `Seek()`). But if the stream you're writing into reports that it [`CanSeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canseek.aspx), it will use that ability to update some headers.

So, make sure that the stream you're writing to returns `false` for `CanSeek()` and everything should work fine.

Comment: You need to call dispose() on ZipOutputStream in order for it to produce a valid zip file. What does dispose() do, if it doesn't need to seek?

Comment: It's similar as with normal output streams: it needs to flush its buffers. And it also writes footers that are required by the file format.

Comment: This mostly worked...now that I've fixed all my bugs. It looks like I was forced to wrap my non-seekable stream in a Ionic.Zip.CountingStream for this to work. Any idea why this is?

Comment: It needs the current position in the stream to write some of the metadata and many non-seekable streams don't even let you get their `Position`. `CountingStream` is used to take care of that. From what I read in the source code, I thought wrapping in `CountingStream` happens automatically when it's necessary, but I may be wrong.